# Scroll UITableView horizontally using auto layout in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I used `storyboard` with `autolayout` enable.  I put a `UIScrollView` in `storyboard`.  Then drag a `UITableView` over the `scrollview`.  I set the table view's width bigger than the scroll view's width.  I then set the constraints with the trailing space to `scrollview` with a negative number and `storyboard` fill all other constraints without error.  The structure look like:

```
  UIView
    UIScrollView
       UITableView
```

in code, I set the scroll view content size:

```
 self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 400);
```

the size matches table view's size.  But it doesn't work.  The table view will not scroll horizontally.  What I am doing wrong and how to make a `UITableView` scroll horizontally.  I mean the whole table, not the each cell scroll horizontally.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make sure that the table view isn't capturing the touches - play with `userInteractionEnabled` on the views involved.